# My js array wont display with console.log in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, console.log

`console.log` doesn't display what I want it to show in my chrome browser dev console.

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>

 </head>

 <body>
  <script src="script.js">
       console.log(amazingCars);
       var amazingCars =["BMW","Lexus","Ford","Mercedes"]; 
       amazingCars.pop();
       console.log(amazingCars);
       amazingCars.sort();
       console.log(amazingCars);
       amazingCars.length;
       console.log(amazingCars.length);
   </script> 
 </body>

</html>
```

The directions for the assignment are the following:

```
Link the JavaScript page to the HTML page.
Create an array named amazingCars that contains four values:
    BMW
    Lexus
    Ford
    Mercedes
Remove the last value from the array
Next, sort the array in alphabetical order
Lastly, find the length of the array
```

I dont understand why it isn't displaying or the reason of this issue

Comment: remove the src from the script tag

Comment: the first `console.log(amazingCars)` is **before** you define **var amazingCars = []**. It's **undefined** at that position.

Comment: Also, `amazingCars.length;` does absolutely nothing. Anyway, *either* state a `src` that links to an external file, *or* put the JS code inside the tags. Not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are putting your JS code in html just add them between`<script></script>` tag.

You do not need to add `src` for script unless your `JavaScript` code is coming from a separate script file.

> The **src** attribute specifies the **URL of an external script file**.
>
> If you want to run the same JavaScript on several pages in a web site,
>   you should create an external JavaScript file, instead of writing the
>   same script over and over again. Save the script file with a .js
>   extension, and then refer to it using the **src** attribute in the
>   `<script>` tag

.

As per the instructions that you are following : **"Link the JavaScript page to the HTML page."**

1. Create another file "index.js" in your project directory.
2. Move your js code into the `index.js` file in your project directory and then use :

   `<script src="index.js"></script>` in your HTML.

Comment: Ya I kept it in the html when I should of been putting it in the .js, I got it now thank you

Comment: Happy to help  :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `<script src="script.js">` to `<script>`.

Alternatively you can keep it this way and create a `script.js` file and copy paste all the code you have inside the `<script>` tag to the file. This file need to be in the same folder as your `index.html` file.

Comment: or create the file, and put the contents of the script tag in the file as per the assignment

Comment: I did that, it seemed to fix it though the homework still tells me to link them how do I do with without ruining it

Comment: `type` is not needed in html5 spec...unless it is **not** javascript

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make the `<script src="index.js"></script>` seperate from the code in the head, also unless if you have a seperate javascript file you dont need the src part at all, and secondly the first console.log outputs it before definition, creating an error. I hope this helped

Comment: I got thanks, the only issue is the HW wants me to link them which I don't understand how without ruining it again

Comment: @Ern Make a folder, name it whatever you want. Put your index.html in there and make a new file called index.js, put all of your javascript there than delete the code between the script elements. That way the script src references to a index.js file and the code should work how you want it to after you delete the first console.log